# A question about the Kakeya problem

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, measure-theory

Besicovich proved a long time ago that a straight line segment of fixed length could be rotated 360
degrees within a subset S of the Euclidean plane such that $M(S)$ is arbitrarily small-where M is two-dimensional Lebesgue measure. This solved the most general version of Kakeya's problem, which asked
how small $M(S)$ could be if no further restrictions were placed on $S$. But was it ever proved that $M(S)$
could never actually be zero? I ask because Besicovich also proved that there existed subsets T of the
Euclidean plane such that $M(T)=0$ and such that pairwise disjoint straight line segments of fixed length,
having every possible orientation, were contained in $S$ (as subsets).

Comment: Just a sketch: consider a motion of the needle (unit line segment), (assume) that it can be represented by a continuous and piece-wise $C^1$ curve in the space of Euclidean motions (translations + rotations). Restrict yourself to a $C^1$ portion such that the starting and ending angles are not the same (else there can be no total rotation). By the mean value theorem there exists a point on the path where the rate of change of the angle is non-zero. It should be straight-forward to check that the image of the needle in a neighborhood of that point contains a disk. 

Answer (score 5):

A Kakeya needle set cannot be of measure zero (a line segment cannot be rotated *continuously* within a set of measure 0). See the [blog post by Terry Tao](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/12/31/a-remark-on-the-kakeya-needle-problem/).

However, there are sets of  measure zero within which a line segment can be rotated by a *Baire-1 map* ([link](http://arxiv.org/abs/0901.3456)).

Comment: Thanks very much for providing such a complete and informative 
response

Comment: Hey, you're welcome. It wasn't a huge effort, really.

Comment: In his "Birds and frogs" Dyson attributes the following to Besicovitch: "Gentlemen. Fifty million English speak English you speak. Hundred and fifty million Russians speak English I speak."


Comment: Hi, Wadim. I speak Ukrainian English.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need a set of positive measure to swing a cat, even through 0.00001 radians? Intuitively you need to include a small sector of a circle to rotate a line segment about any of its points as fixed centre; and while the problem would allow you to rotate about a centre that changes, I'm not seeing how you can do without something resembling a small sector. But perhaps that is the point of what you're asking?